# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Connector

Tags: soql, force.com, soap-api

I am trying to query contacts from salesForce account but getting above error.

I generated `enterprise.jar` file from the WSDL downloaded from my account.

I have `wsc-23-min.jar` along with `enterprise.jar` files in `libs` folder.

Below method is used to query contacts

```
private void queryContacts() {
    Log.i(TAG, "Querying for the 5 newest Contacts...");

    ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
    config.setUsername("***@***.com");
    config.setPassword("***");

    try {
        connection = Connector.newConnection(config);
        // query for the 5 newest contacts      
        com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Account.Name " +
                "FROM Contact WHERE AccountId != NULL ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 5");

        if (queryResults.getSize() > 0) {
            for (int i=0;i<queryResults.getRecords().length;i++) {
                // cast the SObject to a strongly-typed Contact
                Contact c = (Contact)queryResults.getRecords()[i];
                Log.i(TAG, " ------------- Id: " + c.getId() + " - Name: "+c.getFirstName()+" "+
                        c.getLastName()+" - Account: "+c.getAccount().getName());
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any help or clue is appreciated.

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I tried all the methods from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247998/noclassdeffounderror-eclipse-and-android) popular question but no luck.

I have others projects in my workspace which are having jar files (in 'libs' folder) and they all work properly. Don’t know whats wrong with salesforce related jar files.

**Edit:**

There is no problem with `wsc-23.jar` file. Only generated `enterprise.jar` through WSDL file causing problems.

Followed [this](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_quickstart_steps.htm) to generate `enterprise.jar` file

Not getting what's wrong with it.

**Edit:**

I did clone git repository and got all respective jar files but when I run following command

```
java -classpath target/force-wsc-30.0.0-uber.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc enterprise.wsdl enterprise.jar
```

getting

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc
```

I dont see `tools` folder in which `wsdlc` file should b thr in `force-wsc-30.0.0-uber.jar` which is causing above error.

If I clone that git repository, I am getting jar file generated but it wont be having `tools` folder and causes `Error: Could not find or load main class com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc`. If I download `force-wsc-29.0.0.jar` and try to run command, it throws error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupDir`.

I am not getting whats gng wrong here.

**Stack trace when I download `force-wsc-29.0.0.jar` and try to build `enterprice.jar` file.**

```
    basavaraj@basavaraj-u12-115:~/Android/library$ java -classpath force-wsc-29.0.0.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc enterprise.wsdl enterprise.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/stringtemplate/v4/STGroupDir
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupDir
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 6 more
```

**Stack trace when I clone git repository and try build `enterprice.jar` file from generated `force-wsc-30.0.0-uber.jar` file.**

```
basavaraj@basavaraj-u12-115:~/Android/library$ java -classpath force-wsc-30.0.0-uber.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc enterprise.wsdl enterprise.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally I got solution for my problem.

It was a matter of executing command with multiple libraries as in [this](http://sforcehacks.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/building-partnerjar-api-file.html) link.

Along with `force-wsc-29.0.0.jar` from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.force.api/force-wsc/29.0.0), download rhino `js-1.7R2.jar` from [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/rhino) and string template `ST-4.0.7.jar` file from [here](http://www.stringtemplate.org/download/).

Navigate to where these files are placed.

Then, run following command

```
$ java -classpath force-wsc-29.0.0.jar:js-1.7R2.jar:ST-4.0.7.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc enterprise.wsdl enterprise.jar
```

Resulting `enterprise.jar` file will be generated in current working directory.

That's it!.

Thanks to [Abhinav Gupta](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/266/abhinav-gupta) and [Andrew Fawcett](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/286/andrew-fawcett) for their continuous support.

Comment: Thanks also - no mention of this anywhere, but it's crucial.

Answer (score 4):

What is your classpath, is it just libs folder or all jars in the lib folder. I think you need to add both wsc and enterprise jar files to the classpath explicitly.

**Edit** 
I realised after checking new github repo for WSC, that it moved to v30 from v23.0, that should hardly make a difference to problem. But as its always good to use latest stable lib, I gave a shot with github repo for WSC and things were working for me. 
Link to new repo : https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc

Here are the steps you need(adding here, as some steps are not correct on repo README, I have to differ from them to make it work):

1) Clone repo :

`$ git clone https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc.git`

2) MVN build

```
$ mvn clean package
```

3) Generate enterprise jar for your wsdl using following command, please replace paths as needed

```
$ java -classpath target/force-wsc-30.0.0-uber.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc ~/Desktop/enterprise.wsdl enterprise.jar
```

4) Create a Java project, add WSC jar(force-wsc-30.0.0-uber.jar) and enterprise.jar to buidpath/classpath. Try running following code, it should be compilable:

```
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.Connector;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.EnterpriseConnection;
import com.sforce.soap.enterprise.sobject.Contact;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException;
import com.sforce.ws.ConnectorConfig;

public class EntTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ConnectionException {
        ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
        config.setUsername("username");
        config.setPassword("password");

        EnterpriseConnection connection = Connector.newConnection(config);

        // query for the 5 newest contacts      
        com.sforce.soap.enterprise.QueryResult queryResults = connection.query("SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Account.Name " +
                "FROM Contact WHERE AccountId != NULL ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 5");

        if (queryResults.getSize() > 0) {
            for (int i=0;i<queryResults.getRecords().length;i++) {
                // cast the SObject to a strongly-typed Contact
                Contact c = (Contact)queryResults.getRecords()[i];
                System.out.println(" ------------- Id: " + c.getId() + " - Name: "+c.getFirstName()+" "+
                        c.getLastName()+" - Account: "+c.getAccount().getName());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know if you run into any more issues.

Comment: Its 'libs' folder and all jars (wsc-23.jar and enterprise.jar) r in that folder.

Comment: try adding all jars explicitly in classpaths, as libs folder will only help picking exploded class files, not individual jar files.

Comment: Tried. Still same error :(

Comment: I edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: I just checked the WSC page, seems latest version is 30, why are you using old one ? Seems its from google code obsolete repo, use the one available on github here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/wsc

Comment: I am trying the gitub steps to see what I get, will let you know in some time.

Comment: Things worked for me with latest WSC, please check my edited answer.

Comment: Thank u for replying. From where do I get force-wsc-30.0.0-uber.jar file? Please share any link

Comment: It will be generated when you will do the above steps

Comment: I followed all d steps and got respective output also but I dont see 'tools' folder in which wsdlc file should b thr in 'target/force-wsc-30.0.0-uber.jar' file which is causing above error.

Comment: Please use API 29, 30 is Spring'14 yet to be fully released by Salesforce.

Comment: @Andrew & Abhinav - If I clone that git repository, I am getting jar file generated but it wont b having 'tools' folder and causes 'Error: Could not find or load main class com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc'... If I download 'force-wsc-29.0.0.jar' and try to run command, it throws error 'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.stringtemplate.v4.STGroupDir'. I am not getting whats gng here.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can share when the above error is thrown? Its really odd you should have a dependency like this on WSC, as its specifically designed to have minimal overhead.

Comment: @AndrewFawcett & Abhinav - I shared stack trace. Please have a look.

Comment: Its looks to be truncated, saying '6 others' at the bottom, I was hoping it would give a clue, but without the full stack trace its hard to tell what is trying to load this. I did find this blog with reference to your error though... http://sforcehacks.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/building-partnerjar-api-file.html

Comment: Try force-wsc-XX.0.0-uber.jar one its having dependencies its 1+mb in size and force-wsc-XX.0.0.jar is 274 KB only. Also for tools folder, do you have JRE or JDK installed ?

Comment: @AbhinavGupta - Currently I am using force-wsc-XX.0.0-uber.jar file itself and yes, I have JRE or JDK installed in my Ubuntu system.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta & Andrew - Thanks a lot for your continuous support. Finally, I got my issue resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try it :
java -cp C:\Salesforce\tools.jar;antlr-4.7.2-complete.jar;js.jar;ST-4.3.jar;force-wsc-47.0.0.jar com.sforce.ws.tools.wsdlc wsdl.xml enterprise.jar

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score -1):

force-wsc-36.1.1.jar;
rhino-1.7.7.jar;
ST-4.0.8.jar

for JDK 1.7 would have to be added in classpath for SOAP 36.1.1 version